# Making ESC key toggle command/insert modes in vim

Tags: vim

Can I set up vim so that ESC key, when pressed in command mode, changes back to insert mode. Currently, if ESC key is pressed in command mode, it just stays in command mode and no change occurs. For this, I will need to do something like following:

```
map <ESC> if mode([expr]) = command
             exec "i"
          else 
             exec "<ESC>"
          endif
```

But this will lead to endless loop.

Is it possible to use ESC key as a toggle between insert and command modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need simple `nnoremap <Esc> i` or beter `nnoremap <Esc> a` to achieve what you need. `map` is recursive version of mapping command so you need to be careful when using it. `n` in the begin stands for `normal` mode mapping you should read `:help map-modes` and `:help recursive_mapping`

Comment: 'a' is better than 'i'. With 'i', it does not work on empty lines. Also, with 'i', if I repeatedly press ESC, the cursor keeps moving to left side. The second problem is avoided by using 'li' instead of 'i'.

Comment: This produces weird "OB" "OC" etc for me when I press a directional key right after `<ESC>`aping from insert to normal mode. I guess `<up>` produces `^[OA` and the leading `^[` is interpreted as `<ESC>` so vim enters insert mode and writes the rest: "OA"... any idea how to prevent that? Cheers